# Why isn't div centering both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to center a logo horizontally and vertically. I have this so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('#theLogo').css({
                position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - $('#theLogo').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() - $('#theLogo').outerHeight())/2
            });
        });
        $(window).resize();
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="theLogo">
    <section id="responsiveLogo" class="logo">September</section>
</div>
```

I'm trying to centre this bit:

```html
<section id="responsiveLogo" class="logo">September</section>
```

Live version is viewable at http://septemberstudio.co.uk/

Comment: 1. it *is* centered for me. 2. because `#responsiveLogo`'s width is 100%?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Is it centered vertically??

Comment: @Archer Ah no - it isn't - of course that is what OP is trying to do.

Comment: I can't find your script in your "live version"... are you sure you put it in ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 sorry it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**SCRIPT**

```
function resizeMe() {
    $('#theLogo').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#theLogo').outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('#theLogo').outerHeight()) / 2,
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeMe();
    });
    resizeMe();
});
```

**CSS**

```
#theLogo {
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid red;/* for testing */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8L9rB/) and [Demo without Css](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8L9rB/1/)

Try without **Script** like,

**CSS**

```
#theLogo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
}
```

[Css Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8L9rB/2/)

Answer (score 1):

rather than using jquery for centering a div use css..

```
#responsiveLogo{
height:vale;
width:value;
position:absolute;
margin:0 auto;
left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use Javascript to center this, plain old CSS works just fine.

```
#theLogo{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width and the height of the logo:

```
#responsiveLogo{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-(LOGO_HEIGHT/2)px;
    margin-left:-(LOGO_WIDTH/2)px;
}
```

Where (`LOGO_HEIGHT/2`) is half of your logo height...

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/WZWNy/)

If the width and height of the logo is dynamic:

```
var element = document.getElementById('responsiveLogo');
element.style.marginLeft = -(element.offsetWidth/2)+'px';
element.style.marginTop = -(element.offsetHeight/2)+'px';
```

Comment: The logo is responsive so the width and height will change. Does this make your suggestion inappropriate?

Comment: No it would just mean you adjusted the margin-left and margin-top using javascript accordingly

Comment: added JS support for 'responsive' logo size. You could just put that in your `resize` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **css** for this kind of issues. For centering, use always: `margin:0px auto;`

[look at this](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="theLogo" style="width:100%">
   <div id="responsiveLogo" class="logo" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">September</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict with an other script (fittext.js i guess).

You could try to put your script at the end of the `<body>` tag, after the fittext script. And this should work.

Edit :

In fact, the conflict might come from `lettering` plugin. So you can just put your script at the end of the `<head>` tag.

Edit 2 :

Try to use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#theLogo').css({
      position:'absolute',
      left: ($(window).width() - $('#theLogo').outerWidth())/2,
      top: ($(window).height() - $('#theLogo').outerHeight())/2
    });
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(window).resize();
  }, 200);
});
```

then if it works, there is really a conflict with your script, try to debug the logo's width using `console.log($('#theLogo').outerWidth());`

Comment: Tried your edit. It didn't work. I've also tried moving it into it's own page and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#theLogo{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -(yourHeight / 2);
  margin-left: -(yourWidth / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.className{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

To center a div only horizontally, you need to specify a width, and an auto value for the left and right margins (you do remember the shorthand declarations in CSS don’t you?). This method works on block level elements (divs, paragraphs, h1, etc). To apply it to inline elements (like hyperlinks and images), you need to apply one additional rule – display:block.

Horizontal and vertical centering with CSS

Center a div both horizontally and vertically with CSS is a bit more tricky. You need to know the dimensions of the div beforehand.

```
.className{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would probably be using CSS, I have not tested the bellow but it should work fine.

```
<style>
.mydiv{
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
</style>
<div class="mydiv"> content </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

What ever was wrong with simply using...

```
#responsiveLogo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The fact that it doesn't vertically align, maybe?

Comment: I see, well that wasn't clear in the requirement "middle of the browser".

Comment: Yeah, that's not clear, but the attempt at positioning the element using both `left` and `top` made it pretty clear ;)